# Why does 0 | "" | {} extends 0 | "" ? true : false returns false

Tags: typescript, types, extends, union-types, conditional-types

```
0 | "" | {} extends 0 | ""  // false
0 | "" | {} extends 0 | {} // true
```

The union `0 | "" | {}` is larger than the union `0 | ""` so it technically extends from it. I am puzzled as to why it returns false.

This question is from the answer to a Typescript type-challenge [AnyOf](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/954). I would appreciate if someone could breakdown the answer for me. In particular I don't understand how Typescript computes `UnionA extends UnionB` to determine whether it is true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword was chosen to match ES6 classes: `class SubClass extends BaseClass...` which means SubClass is a more specialized type.

Knowing this, one problem then become clear: 
`0 | "" | {}` is not a more specialized type than `0 | ""`. Instead of narrowing it down, you added more possibilities for it to handle. So it should indeed return `false`.

You can test the idea of "MoreSpecific extends LessSpecific", for example: `0 | "" extends 0 | "" | {} ? true : false` (result: true).

Another approach is to think about assignments.
`let variable: BaseClass = some_instance_of_SubClass` should be a valid assignment. 
But if you have a value known to be of type `0 | "" | {}` and try `let myVar1: 0 | "" = value;` you'll find that it's not assignable, as none of the members of the union type `0 | ""` allows you to assign {}.

As for `0 | "" | {} extends 0 | {}` leading to true, it’s because of some peculiarities of the empty object type.
You can do such assignments:

```
let test1: {} = ""
let test2: {} = 34
let test3: {} = {"anything you like": "other than null or undefined"}
```

(it is apparently done for some historical purposes, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44520 “It's a concession to back-compat because `{ }` was the top type when generics were introduced”)

Since you can assign anything other than null or undefined to `{}`, anything other than null or undefined extends `{}`. 
`0 | "" | {}` is assignable to type `{}` as none of the values are null/undefined. Therefore, `0 | "" | {}`  is assignable to type `0 | {}`. So "... extends ..." should return true.

The 'extra possibility' of `""` is already covered by the `{}` part of `0 | {}`.